How can I add timestamp to the output from AWS CLI in windows in command prompt?
I am unable to add timestamp to the output from AWS CLI in log file
I have tried through awk but its giving me error
aws s3 --output text sync localPath s3://bucketName --endpoint-url https://s3-vpcurl.com | awk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 }' >> C:\syncFromS3\NASToS3-Log.txt

awk: cmd. line:1: { print strftime([%Y-%m-%d
awk: cmd. line:1:                  ^ syntax error

I wanted to print the logs along with the timestamp in my log file.
for example:-
[2024-04-22 12:20:38] Completed 440 Bytes/949.5 KiB (382 Bytes/s) with 6 file(s) remaining
[2024-04-22 12:20:38] upload: ..\..\syncFromS3\result_90.csv to s3://s3BucketName/IndexFilesCSV/Results/result_90.csv

or is there any other way to do this?
Any help will be appreciated.

Hey, I think you can't put brackets in the function strftime, maybe try without them like so : awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0 }' >> C:\syncFromS3\NASToS3-Log.txt

I have tried but it's still giving the error at that location awk: cmd. line:1: { print strftime(%Y-%m-%d
awk: cmd. line:1:                  ^ syntax error

Maybe try with parenthesis (awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0 }') >> C:\syncFromS3\NASToS3-Log.txt

yes i put the quotes but on getting error its not there anymore

cmd is notoriously crappy when it comes to these things. The standard solution is to save the Awk script in a file and call it with awk -f path\to\file.awk (or replace Windows entirely; this is a much more elegant solution for the longer term).

How about just running date >> C:\syncFromS3\NASToS3-Log.txt before the command? It will put it on a separate line, but it's pretty easy!

fwiw, all of these awk scripts (from the question, from comments) work for me; I'm using GNU awk; the fact you're writing to a windows file (C::\dir\file.txt), and the mention of cmd in the error message, has me thinking your version of awk has some limitations; please update the question with the output from awk --version and type -a awk

You'll need to use double quotes to quote the string, and escape the double quotes in the string:  aws ... | awk "{ print strftime(\"[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]\"), $0 }"

awk expects the format string for strftime to be quoted
try
aws s3 --output text sync localPath s3://bucketName --endpoint-url https://s3-vpcurl.com | awk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 }' >> C:\\syncFromS3\\NASToS3-Log.txt

Make sure the redirection uses double backslashes as path separator on windows.

Great, if this resolved your issue, would appreciate if u accept the answer :)
